Tabulator - xlsx download with hyperlink in cells
My question is related to Tabulator (tabulator.info) - xlsx download with hyperlink in cells.
In tabulator standard/web output we have columns with hyperlinked fields. Is it possible to get the same hyperlinks in excel download?
We are using tabulator 6.2 and external library for XLSX Download (sheetjs)

Question - "Is it possible."
Answer - "Yes"
